# How do I include eps files using TexWorks

Tags: graphics, eps

I am trying to add some EPS  files in text but I got the following error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .eps.
```

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

I installed MikTex 2.9

Comment: Probably you are using `pdflatex` and then you must use `.pdf`, `.png` or `.jpg` images. But you can use `.eps` images with `latex`compiler. Search about `epstopdf` program.

Comment: In addition to Fran's comment: Try to use `pdflatex --shell-escape` for automatic conversion of `.eps` files to `.pdf` ones.